# What is the correct way to connect a second 'static' Azure office365 account without needing to login (credentials already given)?

Tags: php, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

The company that I work for is a very large one with 5000+ employees. Because of that, we have licenses with Azure and all out emails and servers run on their platform.
I’ve build an application for our internal business (intranet). This application uses SSO to login our users and block external users that are not in our tenant. The board came to me, asking if we could use one global e-mail account to manage all company events and announcements via the calendar. I’ve searched for a while now (3 weeks) and could not find anything related to what I am about to do (in PHP).

I need a connection with microsoft graph via php that automatically logs the ‘statically’ given e-mail address in and spits out all the calendar events between 2 dates. The microsoft graph api is full of previews of this but it is all written for ‘public’ e-mail addresses and not the more secure Azure ones.

I have the connection set with a Bearer token but that returns expired by default.

What i have so far:

```
$tenantAppUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/“.$tenantid;
$tenantHostUrl = "login.microsoftonline.com”;
$requesturl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/“.$tenantid."/oauth2/token?api-version=1.6”;

$post_params = array(
   "client_id" => $clientid,
   "client_secret" => $clientsecret,
   "resource" => "https://graph.windows.net/",
   "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
);
$headers = array(
   "POST: " . $tenantAppUrl . " HTTP/1.1",
   "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "Host: " . $tenantHostUrl,
   "cache-control: no-cache",
   'Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($post_params))
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), false);

curl_close($curl);
```

The above returns a Bearer token that has expired 2 hours ago.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff x-ms-request-id: 2f26979b-c336-44a3-a9c9-d4d785758c00 P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN" Set-Cookie: fpc=AsIZpMH6undMozQVDrbmPxTWEVd_AQAAAEeKP9QOAAAA; expires=Fri, 10-May-2019 06:55:04 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2019 06:55:03 GMT Content-Length: 1448 

{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"3599","expires_on":"1554882904","not_before":"1554879004","resource":"https://graph.windows.net/","access_token”:”<thetoken>"}
```

I expect a Bearer token that should be valid for at least 2 hours but it returns expired 2 hours ago instead of that.

Why is this token expired and how do I use the ‘renew’/‘JWT’ protocol in php to extend its usage to 1 month or more?

Keep in mind, this account will not be logged-in by anyone. It needs to happen automatically. (the credentials have been (secure) saved within the intranet admin environment).

And how do I get all the calendar events between 2 dates for Azure accounts? The url below is also described for 'public e-mail addresses.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: You could configure the token lifetime from the default 1hour to 2 hours, and the maximum for the access token is 1day. For the details, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policy-properties).

Comment: Hmm.. i'll try this, but should I not use the refresh token? When I open the application @ portal.azure.com i can see that I already have +20 new tokens created by this code :-).

Comment: I can't get this powershell to work (macOS or Windows). I really think I need the **JWT** protocol

Answer (score 0):

To determine the token lifetime, either the `expires_in` or `expires_on` parameter values could be utilized, per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code):

- `expires_in` How long the access token is valid (in seconds)
- `expires_on` The time when the access token expires. The date is represented as the number of seconds from `1970-01-01T0:0:0Z` UTC until the expiration time. This value is used to determine the lifetime of cached tokens.

In your example the response from `/token` endpoint tells the token will be expired after `3599` seconds or at `2019-04-10 07:55:04` (*in UTC by design*)

To get a local expiration time set `DateTime::setTimezone` ([List of Supported Timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)) as demonstrated below:

```
$expiredOn = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'U', $token->expires_on, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$expiredOn->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki'));
```